# Why did the producers of "This Is Us" use Sylvester Stallone as the "special" star?

Tags: character, casting, this-is-us

One of the main themes of the TV series *This Is Us* is showing how even many years after the accident, the three siblings still have problems dealing with the loss of their father.

In the second season, Kevin (the actor) gets a chance to play in a serious movie with Sylvester Stallone. This brings back old memories, as apparently, his father was a huge fan of "Rocky", which leads to Kevin projecting his father onto Sly. Crap happens.

But why did the producers use Stallone for this purpose? If there was any meaningful movie that his father loved it's the *Police Academy* series, which is mentioned multiple times.

Was Steve "Mahoney" Guttenberg too expensive or something? Because it sounds like producers wanted to put in the show any 1980s star that is willing to play such a minor role, rather than someone important to the plot.

To clarify - this story arc goes like this:

- Kevin gets his big chance to play in a movie
- He is shocked and intimidated to play with his (and his father's) idol
- He projects his deceased father onto his idol
- He messes up and loses the role

But why this idol is Sylvester Stallone if nothing earlier suggests that anyone from the Person family was a huge fan of Sly, while many, many times is mentioned how important for them was the *Police academy*

Comment: Isn't just putting one of these more than #1 names a good enough reason to draw more attention and money to any serie/movie?

Comment: Why would Steve Guttenberg be more expensive than Stallone?

Comment: @steelersquirrel That seems to be more of a rhetorical question.

Comment: https://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2017/08/this-is-us-sylvester-stallone-milo-ventimiglia-rocky

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Yeah, it's a rhetorical question, but it's a valid one

Comment: Getting an a-lister like Stallone is quite the coup.

Comment: @Valorum it is, but getting Sly and then just suddenly making him "special" sounds to me like a total ass pull. It was as if someone said "Let's say who from the 80s star is still alive and would like to play a minor role" rather than "let's get someone who is important to the plot".

Comment: Stallone got the Oscar nod for best supporting actor in 2019. He's far from being an '80s star'. Him joining the show adds star power.

Comment: @steelersquirrel I mean the one from the question. ;-)

Comment: @Valorum yes, he is still a good actor, but here he is placed as a star from "Rocky" (in the context of Kevin/Kevin's dad idol), rather than just as a "famous actor doing a guest star role", which leads to drama as Kevin is projecting his father onto Sly. The whole purpose of this arc goes like this: Kevin gets a good role, and he sees his father's idol as a co-star which makes him think of his father, which leads to messing up and losing the role. But using Sly there makes no sense in the previous context.

Comment: @NapoleonWilson Uhm...you need to clarify more.  I'm only a squirrel :P